# Corona SDK event.target touch/tap

Tags: events, lua, touch, coronasdk, tap

I am trying to use event.target to see which object has been tapped.  I have this function that is called by a local event listener:

```
local param1 = 0

function changeParams(event)
  if( event.target == "op1Up" ) then
    param1 = param1 + 1
  elseif( event.target == "op1Down" ) then
    param1 = param1 - 1
  end
  dispMyParams1.text = ( "Param 1: "..param1 )
end

local op1Up = display.newRect( --[[rect parameters]]-- )
op1Up:addEventListener( "tap", changeParams )
local op1Down = display.newRect( --[[rect parameters]]-- )
op1Down:addEventListener( "tap", changeParams )
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
local param1 = 0

function changeParams(event)
  if( event.target.name == "op1Up" ) then
    param1 = param1 + 1
  elseif( event.target.name == "op1Down" ) then
    param1 = param1 - 1
  end
  dispMyParams1.text = ( "Param 1: "..param1 )
end

local op1Up = display.newRect( --[[rect parameters]]-- )
op1Up.name="op1Up"
op1Up:addEventListener( "tap", changeParams )
local op1Down = display.newRect( --[[rect parameters]]-- )
op1Up.name="op1Down"
```

event.target return reference to the object, you first need to add a property "name" to all objects then try to identify .name there as I shown in the code.

```
op1Down:addEventListener( "tap", changeParams )
```

Comment: Thanks so much!  I would vote you up, but I only have 13 reputation.  :)